# req.session.captcha is not working on different port in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to verify captcha by storing into a `req.session` object.

The express server is running on 8181 and the client on 3000. But in the verify captcha `req.session.captcha` is undefined. Please help me.

**My server code:**

```
var captchapng = require('captchapng');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'abcd',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {maxAge: 1000*60*60*24*30}, //30 days
  }));



app.get('/captcha.png', function (request, response) {
    if(request.url == '/captcha.png') {
        var randNumber = Math.random()*9000+1000;
        var p = new captchapng(80,30,parseInt(randNumber)); // width,height,numeric captcha
        p.color(0, 0, 0, 0);  // First color: background (red, green, blue, alpha)
        p.color(80, 80, 80, 255); // Second color: paint (red, green, blue, alpha)
        var no  = parseInt(randNumber);
        request.session.captcha = no.toString();
        console.log(parseInt(randNumber));
        console.log(request.session);
        var img = p.getBase64();
        var imgbase64 = new Buffer(img,'base64');
        response.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'image/png'
        });
        response.end(imgbase64);
    } else response.end('');
})

app.get('/verify-captcha', (req, res) => {
    let captcha = req.query.captcha;
    console.log(captcha, req.session);
    if(req.session.captcha === Number(captcha)){
        res.send({message:'verified'})
    }
    else
        res.send({message: "Not Verified!"})
})

app.listen(8181);
```

**My client code:**

index.pug

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
  #image
    img(src="http://localhost:8181/captcha.png")
  #verify
    input(type="text" placeholder="Enter captcha to verify" id="captcha")
    button(type="button") Submit
```

captcha.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(e){
        var captcha = $('#captcha').val();
        alert(captcha)
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8181/verify-captcha?captcha='+captcha,
            type:'GET',
            success: function(data){
                alert(data)
            },
            error: function(err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Could you add your client request code please?

Comment: @VitoMadio client code added.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `app.use(cookieParser());` is the problem...

From express-session documentation:

> Since version 1.5.0, the cookie-parser middleware no longer needs to be used for this module to work. This module now directly reads and writes cookies on req/res. Using cookie-parser may result in issues if the secret is not the same between this module and cookie-parser.

Remove `cookieParser` or use the same secret `app.use(cookieParser('abcd'));`.

Also:

Your client code has a typo:

```
url: 'http://localhost:8181/verify-captch?captcha='+captcha,
```

should be

```
url: 'http://localhost:8181/verify-captcha?captcha='+captcha,
```

In you server code you are comparing String with Number, should be like this:

```
app.get('/verify-captcha', (req, res) => {
    let captcha = req.query.captcha;
    console.log(captcha, req.session);
    if(req.session.captcha === captcha){ // removed Number() here
        res.send({message:'verified'})
    }
    else
        res.send({message: "Not Verified!"})
})
```

**Edit:**

Looks like for `$.ajax` to send cookies you have to add

```
xhrFields: {
  withCredentials: true
},
```

Final client code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(e){
        var captcha = $('#captcha').val();
        alert(captcha)
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8181/verify-captcha?captcha='+captcha,
            type:'GET',
            xhrFields: {
              withCredentials: true
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data)
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-y6dzda (note: requires server running on localhost:8181)

Comment: I have tried but getting same req.session.captcha undefined.

Comment: I have the code running and it works - I have noticed few issues and addressed them in the answer update. Still figuring out why your `req.session.captcha` is undefined...

Comment: 8846
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2018-09-24T18:19:26.125Z,
     originalMaxAge: 2592000000,
     httpOnly: true },
  captcha: '8846' }
8846 Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2018-09-24T18:20:13.534Z,
     originalMaxAge: 2592000000,
     httpOnly: true } }
you can see captcha is missing in verify-captcha api's log.

Comment: Sorry for misleading you - I've made my setup exactly as yours and managed to fix the issue. Hopefully this is it. See updated answer...

Answer (score 0):

Seems you haven't set your session as it should, change lines as follows:

```
app.get('/captcha.png', function (request, response) {
var session = request.session; // add this 
if(request.url == '/captcha.png') {
    var randNumber = Math.random()*9000+1000;
    var p = new captchapng(80,30,parseInt(randNumber)); // width,height,numeric captcha
    p.color(0, 0, 0, 0);  // First color: background (red, green, blue, alpha)
    p.color(80, 80, 80, 255); // Second color: paint (red, green, blue, alpha)
    var no  = parseInt(randNumber);
    session.captcha = no.toString(); //change this line
    console.log(parseInt(randNumber));
    console.log(session); // and change this
    var img = p.getBase64();
    var imgbase64 = new Buffer(img,'base64');
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'image/png'
    });
    response.end(imgbase64);
} else response.end('');
})
```

this should set the session, because you were assigning no.toString() to request.session.captcha which isn't yet set, what exists instead is request.session.

Comment: well, i am getting captcha value from client side but the problem is in req.session.captcha. it is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

This is an older issue but I faced the exact same scenario today. Some hours of searching found this workaround.

My environment :

- Angular CLI: 9.1.6
- Node: 10.16.2
- OS: win32 x64
- Angular: 9.1.7

If there is a better way do let all know.
Steps I tried and was not successful:

- Tried the  withCredentials: true - but did nor work for me as I have CORs enabled and it is not allowed as part of the content protection policy.
- As OP pointed out Some how my session data was sent with each request (each time "undefined")

It all depends on the way you are planning the CAPTCHA (in this particular case)
In my case - I'm using a sessionStore (part of request) that contains a list of all sessions from user perspective. Each try is considered as a session. For the login screen I always consider using the last - but each case could be different.

What I ended up doing is to iterate and pick the last item from the list and I did get the captcha data element.

```
var captchaFromUser = "";
    if(req.sessionStore){
        if(req.sessionStore.sessions){
            var idKeys = Object.keys(req.sessionStore.sessions);
            if(req.sessionStore.sessions[idKeys[idKeys.length-1]]){
                 captchaFromUser =
                 JSON.parse(req.sessionStore.sessions[idKeys[idKeys.length-1]]).captcha;
            }
        }

    }
```